# PageLoad not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code doesn't go into page load. What is the Problem in this. I have used breakpoint on pageload but it doesn't go into page load. why is this happening? Help me do this

```
   public partial class UploadVideo : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public string UploadVideoToFolder()
    {
        string vTitle = "";
        string vDesc = "";
        string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ProductVideos/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["title"]);



        HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        if (MyFileCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            // Save the File
            try
            {
                MyFileCollection[0].SaveAs(FilePath);
                return "1";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "-1";
            }
        }
        else
            return "-1";

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = UploadVideoToFolder();
        Response.Write(result);
    }
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Check debugging enabled or not in the web.config file. and try autoeventwireup=true

Answer (score 1):

In these states usually problem is easy to resolve, for example you wrote a incorrect name in `Response.Redirect("name.aspx");`

Comment: i got the problem. It was my mistake. Actually a silly mistake.